# Left translation of automorphic form satisfies $K$-finiteness?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms

Does a left translation of an automorphic form satisfy left $K$-finiteness?

Let $F$ be a number field and $G$ is an algebraic group. Let $\phi$ is an automorphic form on $G$. Let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup of $G(A)$.

Then $\phi$ has $K$-finiteness.

For arbitrary $x$, let $\phi_x(g)=\phi(xg)$. Then I am wondering whether $\phi_x$ has also $K$-finiteness.

Decompose $K=K_{\infty}K^{\infty}$. I checked $K^{\infty}$-finiteness of $\phi_x$ but cannot check $K_{\infty}$-finiteness.

Does this hold? If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: Though "left translation" appears in the title, it does not appear in the question, nor do you give a good context. Please amplify?

Comment: @paul, oh I am very sorry. I edited my question. Would you see it again? Thank you!

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that the usual term is "is $K$-finite", not "has $K$-finiteness".  Anyway, doesn't it just mean that the set of $K$-translates lies in a finite-dimensional space?  Then testing the $K$-finiteness of $\phi_x$ is just testing the $x^{-1}K x$-finiteness of $\phi$, which we have already established.

Comment: @LSpice, since $\phi_x$ is the left translate of $\phi$, I think it is not of the $x^{-1}Kx$-finiteness.

Comment: Is $\phi$ $K$-finite on the left? Or right?

Comment: @Subhajit, Usually K-finite means about right K translation.

Comment: Whether you want my answer or Paul Garrett's depends on whether the full group is acting from the same side as the compact subgroup, or from the opposite side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumable (in an automorphic forms context with contemporary left-right conventions) you mean that $\varphi$ is *right* $K$-finite. This could apply to any (complex-valued) function $\varphi$ on a topological group $G$, with compact subgroup $K$. It means that the space of functions obtained by right translation $R_k$ by $k\in K$ is finite-dimensional. These are functions $R_k\varphi(g)=\varphi(gk)$.

Left translation $T_x$ by $x$ stabilizes that collection of functions, because left and right translation commute: $T_xR_k\varphi=R_kT_x\varphi$.

Comment: I am very sorry for late reply and always thank you very much! I am learning much from your answers.

Comment: Dear Prof. @Paul, if you are fine, would you take a look my another question related to Harish-Chandra isomorphism? Thank you very much! https://mathoverflow.net/questions/357661/is-there-a-functorial-relation-of-center-of-universal-enveloping-algebra

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes at the finite places, but no at the infinite place.

Because each finite-dimensional complex representation of a totally disconnected group factors through a finite quotient, a vector is $K_\textrm{f}$-finite iff its stabilizer in $G(\mathbb{A}_\textrm{f})$ is open in that group, and this condition is obviously invariant under right-translation by $G(\mathbb{A}_\textrm{f})$.

On the other hand, at infinite places this is false: translating a $K_\infty$-finite vector by an element of $G(F_\infty)$ will generically give a non-$K_\infty$-finite vector.   For example consider the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ on $\left\{ f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\setminus{0}\to \mathbb{C} \vert f(rx) = r^{\frac12+it}f(x) \right\}$.  A vector is $\mathrm{SO}(2)$-finite iff its restriction to the circle is a trigonometric polynomial.  But it is easy to check that for essentially any $g\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\setminus\mathrm{SO}(2)$, if $f(x)$ is a non-constant trigonometric polynomial then  $f(xg)$ isn't.

This is one of the motivation for passing to $(\mathfrak{g},K_\infty)$-modules: since $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite-dimensional representation of $K_\infty$, its action on smooth vectors preserves $K$-finiteness.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply but thank you very much for your kind reply. Since I didn’ t know the connection of modular form and automorphic form, I studied modular form for a while to understand your answer. But I couldn’t understand your last comment. Why the finite dimension of $\mathfrak{g}$ guarantee the $\mathfrak{g}$-action preserves the $K$-finiteness?

Comment: Let $v$ be a $K$-finite smooth vector in a representation $V$ of a Lie group $G$. Then $v$ lies in a $K$-invariant subspace $U$.  If $X\in\frak{g}$ then $Xv$ lies in the image of a map $\frak{g}\otimes U\to V$, whose image is a f.d. rep. of $K$ since its domain is the tensor product of two such representations.